# A better way to test a match when iterating over multiple objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am having trouble with a small function I have written in that I cannot get the value to return properly. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than using a `.forEach` loop.

```
    var userSelectedBook = { id: 1234 };
    var bookList = [
        {
            id: 5678,
            color: "blue"
        },
        {
            id: 1234,
            color: "red"
        }
    ];
    
    function getBookColor(bookList, userSelectedBook) {
      const color = bookList.forEach(book => {
        if (book.id === userSelectedBook.id) {
          return book.color;
        }
      });
      return color;
    }
```

In the above case, when I call `getBookColor()` I would expect to receive the response "red" because I am passing the `userSelectedBook` where the ID is `1234`.

However I only get `undefined` even though putting a console log within the `if` statement does show the correct `color`.

Comment: As a sidenote, if the `userSelectedBook` is not actually a full book object (it doesn't have a color), then I would call it `userSelection` or some other name to avoid confusion.

A more typical API would be to have a `findBookById` function. Such a function only cares about book ids, and doesn't need to know what a user selection object is, or that books have colors. You can then do `findBookById(userSelection.id)?.color` to get the selected color if any.

Comment: @Domino thanks, but these names are just obfuscated from my actual code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is a `void` function ( always returns `undefined` ), you need to use `find` instead.

```
function getBookColor(bookList, userSelectedBook) {
  return bookList.find(book => book.id === userSelectedBook.id)?.color;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this still returns `undefined`? https://jsfiddle.net/oswhbzL7/

Comment: I think you meant to use `find` which will return a single element, not `filter` which returns an array all books with the same id.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's `find`, @Domino, thanks to notify.

Comment: @user1486133, please check https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/gopx5d6n/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const bookList = [{id: 5678,color: "blue"},{id: 1234,color: "red"}];

function getColorForId(list,id){
 return list.find(b=>b.id==id)?.color ?? "none";
}

['5678', 1234, 12345].forEach(t=>
 console.log(`The book ${t} is ${getColorForId(bookList,t)}.`)
);
```